# Angular 7 How to upload files from multiple inputs

Tags: angular, typescript

I using Angular 7 with typescript and my question is:
How to upload files from multiple inputs in html like this:

```
<input type="file" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
<input type="file" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
<input type="file" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
```

I know about multiple but I can't use it because I need to change the name of each file to value of enum in spring boot app

Comment: Well, you don't make multiple file inputs. You have one input element with multiple attribute to enable the user to upload multiple files. Then you use FormData to append selected files and make a request to the server using HttpClient.

Comment: @Mateusz Sobczak Is there a reason for not using a single input?

Comment: @LuisRico because I need to change the name of each file to value of enum in spring boot app

Comment: Please have a look I hope it's helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51587241/how-to-upload-multiple-files-in-angular-6-with-addmore-button

Comment: posible duplicate of [How to Upload multiple files in Angular 6 with ADDMORE button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51587241/how-to-upload-multiple-files-in-angular-6-with-addmore-button?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create multiple file input fields. One is enough and You can select multiple files in it to upload.

```
<input type="file" name="img" multiple>
```

The multiple attribute is a boolean attribute.
When present, it specifies that the user is allowed to enter more than one value in the  element. To select multiple files, hold down the CTRL or SHIFT key while selecting.

Answer (score 0):

create one input fields and set multiple params for it.

```
<input type="file" multiple>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a single input you can still rename each file independently:

```js
  onFileChange(files: FileList) {
     Array.from(files).forEach(file => {
       //ADD CODE TO RENAME THE FILE
      });
 }
```